# "No view is registered with id: codespaces.explorerDetails" and "No view is registered with id: codespaces.explorer"

Tags: visual-studio-code, explorer, codespaces

I am new to Visual Studio Code. I have configured my environment for C/C++ development and everything is working.

However, when starting VS Code, I receive these notifications in the bottom right corner.

- "No view is registered with id: codespaces.explorerDetails"
- "No view is registered with id: codespaces.explorer"

Comment: why use `codespaces`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I don't have either C++ nor codespaces extension installed.

Answer (score 63):

A deprecated Codespaces extension `ms-vsonline.vsonline` causes these error messages. But the extension does not appear in the user interface.

You can uninstall the deprecated extension by pasting the following command into a Windows PowerShell terminal:

```
code --uninstall-extension ms-vsonline.vsonline
```

The solution was found here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144971

Comment: where should i paste this particular command?

Comment: @Thefutureguy123 You can paste it into a powershell (on windows), or your default console on linux/macos. you can also use the integrated terminal of VSCode (Terminal -> New Terminal)

Comment: @banzhe This fixed it for me.. been searching for a fix for a couple of weeks.. thank you!  Had to issue the command in Powershell, which I almost never use.

Answer (score 6):

For those on a Mac, you may need to set 'code' in the PATH command, before implementing the above solution.

Open the Command Palette (Cmd+Shift+P) in Visual Studio Code and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.